# Trying to align a div to the right using CSS

Tags: html, css

Here's the CSS:

```
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

And HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Social Bar</h3>
  <p>The sticky social bar will stick to the screen when you scroll.</p>
</div>
```

I tried to add padding-right:0px but it didn't work here:

```
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  padding-right:0px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong...

Thanks

Comment: added HTML sorry wasn't there...

Comment: This is actually taken from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_social_bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `right: 0;` to the `.icon-bar`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;height:2000px;}

.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right:0;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a> 
  <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a> 
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Social Bar</h3>
  <p>The sticky social bar will stick to the screen when you scroll.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align absolute/fixed div to right then you just use `right: 0;`

```
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

`padding: 0px` will mean just.. well.. that this div will not have padding  (empty space) on right side inside it, so it has nothing to do with aligning.
[Read about padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) and [positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) because like I said they are completly different things.